# depcheck with Node.js - finding require('x') where x is not in package.json

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I found this library called depcheck:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck

At first I just assumed that it did what I want - find modules that are used in the code but not declared in package.json, but all it does it look for unused dependencies. I am looking for the exact reverse- dependencies that are used in the code but not declared in package.json.

Is there such an NPM module that can do this? I can't find it. The reason this matters is that when deploying Node.js applicatons it's very common that we are missing a dependency in package.json that we are using our code because one of us forgot to include the --save option when running npm install x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a suitable solution to this problem so I created my own that we are using in production with Mocha testing -, I hope it might be useful to you also:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-dep-check

Answer (score 1):

[dependency-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-check) looks like it does what you need.